# iPad2 Wifi Issues

Tags: ipad, wifi

My iPad2 works if it is placed next to the Wifi router. It does not detect WiFi if it is just one foot away. The problem seemed to have appeared all of a sudden. Does this look like a problem with the iPad2 hardware?

I have seen discussions on iPad2 WiFi problems and the common solutions to reset settings, including reseting completely did not work.

Comment: Have you tried completely restoring the device, and setting it up as a new iPad, instead of restoring the backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the WiFi is actually working but does not get signal range = Antenna.

If you did not do any hardware stuff like changing battery and others (accidentally breaking something), or dropped your iPad ect...

It does look like a hardware problem that needs to be looked at by professionals.

It might be the WiFi antenna is disconnected ?

If you are up to the task, you can try to [repair the WiFi antenna](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A72lGC5v-pg) your self, but it does [require skills](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPad+Wi-Fi+Teardown/2183).

Comment: Wow. That's pretty much sounds like a good reason. I am not up to repairing antenna myself. I'd better consult the service center.